# UIToolBar loading incorrectly

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitoolbar

After changing some of the build settings to release the app, I found that the UIToolbar now doesn't load correctly.

I'm pretty sure it isn't a problem with the code, but instead an Xcode setting that I changed by accident - can anyone help?

Here are screenshots of before and after the problem.

Before:

[image: Before problem]

After:

[image: After Problem]

Comment: check autosizing of view and toolBar

Comment: Both have autosizing selected, and have always had so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're resetting sizes somewhere (look at how the logout button is offset and to the upper left).  Also, it looks like there's another blue button that you can just see the edge on the right hand side.  It looks like you're setting the item frames incorrectly. You may want to do an NSLog before and after on the relevant items to see what they're being set to, then you can track down who's setting them.

Comment: Boom, found it. I was changing the frame and it wasn't previously registering the frame change. Thanks!